# Find eigenvalues of operator

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, tensor-products

Let $A$ be a linear operator which acts on the vector space $V=\langle x_1,x_2, \ldots,x_n\rangle$. Suppose we know its eigenvalues - $\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \ldots, \lambda_n.$

Now consider the vector space $V^{(2)} \subset {\rm Sym}^2 V$ generated by elements $x_i x_j, i<j,$ $\dim V^{(2)}=\binom{n}{2}.$ Let us extend the operator $A$ on $V^{(2)}$    by linearity and by $A(x_i x_j)=A(x_i)A(x_j)$. Denote the extension by $A^{(2)}$  *and suppose that $A^{(2)}$ is an injective endomorphism of $V^{(2)}$.*

**Question.** What is the eigenvalues of the $A^{(2)}?$ 
My first answer    was that the set of eigenvalues consists of elements  $\lambda_i \lambda_j, i<j$ but simple examples with small $n$  show  that is wrong answer.

**Edit.** We may assume  that $A$ is  a permutation of the basis vectors.

Comment: To write $< x_1,x_2, \ldots,x_n>$ is not proper usage; I changed it to $\langle x_1,x_2, \ldots,x_n\rangle$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Can we assume that $A$ is injective? Also, when we write $x_ix_j$, what do we mean?

Comment: @bartgol that wouldn't be enough: the map 
$$
A = \pmatrix{2&1\\0&1}
$$
fails similarly

Comment: yes,I mean that $A$ is injective. $x_i x_j=x_j x_i$ and it is an element of the symmetric algebra of the vector space.Please see an exmple below.

Comment: So, is $x_ix_j$ the same as the symmetric part of the matrix $x_i x_j^T$ (or better, the vectorization of that)?

Comment: @bartgol that is certainly one way to think about it.  Leox is ultimately using some form of the [symmetric tensor product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_tensor)

Comment: Well, I'm puzzled then. Cause if that's the definition of $x_ix_j$, then the statement should be true, since
$$
A(x_ix_j)=Ax_i Ax_j = \frac{1}{2}(Ax_i (Ax_j)^T + Ax_j (Ax_i)^T))=\frac{\lambda_i\lambda_j}{2}( x_ix_j^T+x_jx_i^T)=\lambda_i\lambda_j x_ix_j.
$$

Edit: assuming $x_i,x_j$ are eigenvectors of $A$.

Comment: @bartgol that assumes that the $x_i$ are the eigenvectors, which they are apparently not necessarily

Comment: Sure, but you can always expand $x_i,x_j$ on the eigenvector basis of $A$, no?

Comment: Aaaah, but that brings in all the eigenvectors and shuffles together the eigenvalues...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you talk about the eigenvalues of $A^{(2)}$ over $V^{(2)}$, you assume that the image of $A^{(2)}$ lies within $V^{(2)}$ (or, in other words, that $V^{(2)}$ is an invariant subspace of $A \otimes A$).  Note, however, that this is not generally the case.  For example, we can consider the map $A$ over $\langle x_1,x_2 \rangle$ defined by
$$
Ax_1 = Ax_2 = x_1
$$
or in terms of matrices, $A = \left(\begin{smallmatrix}1&1\\0&0\end{smallmatrix}\right)$.

Note that $A^{(2)}(x_1x_2) = x_1x_1 \notin V^{(2)}$.

Because $A^{(2)}$ (as restricted to $V^{(2)}$) is not an endomorphism, it doesn't make sense to talk about its "eigenvalues".

---

Suppose that $A$ permutes the vectors $\{x_i\}$ by some permutation $\sigma \in S_n$.  That is, $Ax_i = x_{\sigma(i)}$.  For convenience, let $x_{ij} = x_ix_j$.

Note that $A^{(2)}$ is itself a permutation of the basis vectors $\{x_i x_j:i<j\}$.  In particular, we have
$$
A^{(2)}:x_{ij} \mapsto x_{\sigma(i)\sigma(j)}
$$
Ultimately, the eigenvalues depend on the cycle decomposition of this new permutation.  This depends only on the cycle decomposition of the original permutation.

For example: suppose that $A$ is the map
$$
x_1 \to x_2 \to x_3 \to x_1\\
x_4 \to x_5 \to x_4
$$
That is, $A$ has the cycle decomposition $(1 2 3)(45)$.  Then $A^{(2)}$ can be written out as
$$
x_{12} \to x_{23} \to x_{13} \to x_{12}\\
x_{45} \to x_{45}\\
x_{14} \to x_{25} \to x_{34} \to x_{15} \to x_{24} \to x_{35} \to x_{14}
$$
If we were to list the elements of $\{x_{ij}:i<j\}$ in lexicographical order, we could rewrite the above as
$$
1 \to 5 \to 2 \to 1\\
10 \to 10\\
3 \to 7 \to 8 \to 4 \to 6 \to 9 \to 3
$$
So that the new permutation has the cycle decomposition
$$
(1 \;5\; 2)(3\; 7\; 8\; 4\; 6\; 9)(10)
$$
So, we're looking for the eigenvalues of a permutation that decomposes into one $3$-cycle, one $6$-cycle, and one $1$-cycle.  Our eigenvalues will be each of the roots of $\lambda^3 = 1$, each of the roots of $\lambda^6 = 1$, and each of the roots of $\lambda = 1$.

Comment: Well, suppose  that $A(V^{(2)})=V^{(2)}$. I will correct.

Comment: First of all, you meant $A(V^{(2)}) \subseteq V^{(2)}$.  Second of all, the fact that $V^{(2)}$ isn't usually an invariant subspace is a hint that whatever the answer will be, it won't be "nice"; at least, if we're going to get a nice answer, we need a nice characterization of the maps $A$ that make $A^{(2)}$ an endomorphism.  It would help if you could provide some context for this question.  For example: why are you asking it?  Does this come out of some bigger problem?  Also, have you heard of the antisymmetric tensor product?

Comment: For example, let $n=6$ and let    $$
A( x_{{3}})=x_{{2}},A(x_{{2}})=x_{{3}},A(x_{{1}})=x_{{1}},A(x_{{6}})=x_{{6}},A(x_{{5}})=x_{{4}},A(x_{{4}})=x_{{5}}.
$$ In this case we have that $A$ is an endomorphism. The eigenvalues of $A$  is $$
[-1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
$$  and the eigenvalues of $A^{(2)}$ is $$[-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]$$  so it is not $\lambda_i \lambda_j$.     P.S. Ok, I will looking about antisymmetric product. I hope  that there is a "nice" answer.

Comment: @Leox can we assume that $A$ is necessarily a permutation of the vectors $\{x_i\}$?

Comment: Yes,  we may assume  that $A$ is a permutation.

Comment: @Leox maybe you should ask a separate question to find out which maps $A$ will work for us

Comment: I have edited the question and assume that $A$ is a permutation.

Comment: See my latest edit

Comment: Please see my another question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1404651/find-trace-of-linear-operator